# Trouble uploading a codeigniter website to the ftp

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, http-status-code-404, warnings

I have been trying to upload a codeigniter website but for some reason it shows errors i do not have on my local environment. These errors popped up after i uploaded the files:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   [basepath]/application/config/constants.php:1)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 568

404 Page Not Found

> The page you requested was not found.
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader.so' -
>   /opt/alt/php56/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader.so: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0

I have changed the database settings so that it would connect to the online database. I also followed the correct guide which suggested which setting to change to be able to access the files on the new server. I am however pestered by errors which seem to come from codeigniter's own files.

Has anyone encountered any of there errors, or can anyone make sense of them? Help would really be appreciated!

Comment: about Cannot modify header information - headers already sent... - consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: I know about sending headers and that it cannot be sent again if any content is outputted after sending the header. The question is more that my local environment does not have this error at all, and it only occurs on the online environment, so as far as i know, it cannot be my own code.

Comment: output buffering could be on for one, while the other isn't. a byte order mark also counts as output, `constants.php:1` the "1" here is a sign of that. Make sure the file is UTF-8 without BOM. I could be wrong here, but then again... I could be right. Even a simple space before the opening PHP tag.

Comment: It's odd. The local environment works perfecly fine, and the second error is nothing to worry about. So it actually is a problem with the headers... I am stumped. I am going to try uploading a clean CodeIgniter installation and see if that works.

Comment: Ok Steven; I hope everything works out for you, *cheers*

Comment: Thanks! I just tried uploading a clean site and it works. I am going to upload bits and peices of my site and see where it goes wrong. Thanks for your help! It helped alot!

Comment: You're very much welcome Steven :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs due to Ioncube security extension [website](http://ioncube.com).
As far as i know, this error could be caused by unsupported version of PHP. You have installed PHP 5.6 and Ioncube may still not support it. You should upgrade your ioncube extension or downgrade PHP.

Comment: I consulted with the hosting provider. The second error states that IonCube cannot be found, and that is because it does not support the latest PHP version, so they disabled it. In other words, the second error actually has nothing to do with my site not loading.

Comment: ionCube Loaders have been available for PHP 5.6 since October 17th 2014 - yes, 2014.  Support was introduced into the 4.7 series of Loaders. The latest series is version 5, which includes support for running files from Encoder version 9, running files encoded specifically for PHP 5.6, and also the ionCube24 service, which offers free realtime intrusion protection to block execution of malware that gets introduced through exploiting any code placement or modification vulnerability. Using the version 5 series and enabling ionCube24 is highly recommended. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.